# Connect from iphone to LDAP on a non-standard port

Tags: ldap, iphone, ipad, apache-ds

I asked on superuser, it was migrate to  the apple stack exchange site and it was suggested I ask here.

This feels like cross posting but...

I've tried a quite a few different sequences, such as appending the port to the server address, but all to no avail. Has anyone been able to connect to an LDAP that runs on a different port than 389? If so, I would appreciate confirmation that it is possible and steps on how you set things up would be even better.

My LDAP is apacheDS and the port it runs on is not 389, so I'm at a loss how an iPhone or iPad can connect to the LDAP.

Comment: When you say connect to an LDAP on port other than 389, what exactly do you mean by 'connect'? Are you using an app? Are you trying to write Objective-C code to do this?

Comment: on the iphone or ipad you are able to add an LDAP source for contacts

Comment: Why aren't you running your LDAP server on the standard ports?  Have you disabled 389, and are you only allowing ldaps over 636 or something else?  You don't plan on permitting authentication over 389 since it is in the clear right?  Can you just setup a NAT so that 389 traffic gets to the ldap server?

Comment: I guess you are right @Zoredache as an obscure port won't really obscure it from connection attempts. It just happened to get setup that way.